# Passing a props to another component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am coding a restaurant reviews app with Vue.js and Django REST Framework.
User can "POST" pictures on their reviews.

As soon as the user click a `'Create review'` button, this function is triggered:

```
addReview () {
  let endpoint = `/api/restaurant_review/`;
  let method = "POST";
  apiService(endpoint, method, { maps: this.$route.params.maps, review_author: 1 })
    .then(res => {          
          let review_id = res.id
          console.log(review_id)
          return review_id                  
        })
  },
```

So I also get a `review_id` from my response. I pass it to an other component where the user can upload pictures this way:

```
<ReviewEditor
 :id= "review_id"/>
```

In my `data()` I have:

```
review_id: 0,
```

So in my ReviewEditor component, I get the id like this:

```
props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
  }
```

And then:

```
onUpload() {
      const fd = new FormData();
      let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN,           
        }
      };
      fd.append('picture_1', this.selectedFile)
      fd.append('restaurant_review', this.id)
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outside_pic/', fd, axiosConfig)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
    }
```

My onUpload() function works well if I pass manually the `id`, but if I do it dynamically with `this.id`, I have an error message telling me that `'restaurant_id' = 0`, and therefore doesn't exists. I also tried `review_id: 0,` but with no luck either.

Comment: Didn't you forgot a `this.review_id = res.id` in your `then` callback ? Without it, your `review_id` data property will never change.

Comment: I changed as stated but now I have `Unexpected keyword 'this'`

Comment: @TotoBriac please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63443669/edit) with the code you now have. You should only have to change `let review_id = res.id` to `this.review_id = res.id`

Comment: Please write your comment as an answer so I can vote for it :)

Comment: further to the comment above, using the chrome dev tools to inspect your components would allow you to see that the ID was not getting passed correctly. It's a really useful tool for debugging :)